# Can't access CChildView in CWinAppEx

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an Single document MFC application in C++ and I'm wondering if I can call a function declared in the CChildView from my CWinAppEx class.

CChildView is of type CWnd.

So far I tried:

```
CChildView* view = (CChildView*)m_pActiveWnd;
```

And

```
CWnd* pWndMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
CChildView* view = (CChildView*) pWndMain;
```

I'm relatively new in this type of architectures so I hope someone can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting doesn't help, because the main window is not a CChildView class nor is it inherited from one. It is a CFrameWnd, which is the class that manages views in the Doc/View Architecture.

You can get a pointer to a view windows like this.

```
 CView* pActiveView = ((CFrameWnd*) AfxGetMainWnd())->GetActiveView();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works, but I've decided to use another approach then this.